Are all polynomial of this form bijective?
I believe that all polynomial of the following form are bijective (from strict monotonicity), $ \forall a \in R$ where $n=2k$ and $k \in N$, (n is a positive even integer).
$$
P(x) = (x+a)^n - x^n 
= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{n!(n-k)}{k!(n-k)!} \, x^{n-k-1} a^k
$$
However, I do not know how to prove (or disprove) it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Just prove that its derivative is $>0$ for any $x$ !

@JeanMarie. What you said is valid only for $a>0$. For the other sign, the derivative is negative, and for $a=0$, the assertion is false.

You are right : I should have said that the derivative is either $>0$ for $a>0$ or $<0$ if $a<0$ (the case $a=0$ is uninteresting). But I am still puzzled by the fact that the asker hasn't thought to use derivatives...

This is true of any convex function, of which $x^{2k}$ clearly is.

@CalvinLin. I don’t think it’s true for any convex function. Consider for example $|x|$, which is convex, but $|x+a|-|x|$ isn’t bijective.

Since it's not true when $a=0$, you can't say $\forall a\in\mathbb R$. This is a relatively minor point but it's not good to get in the habit of ignoring special cases.

@Pranay It's for a strictly convex function. We need the derivative to be $> 0$.

@CalvinLin. Ah okay. Let me think about that

@JeanMarie, I thought about it, but the derivative simplifies to: $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k-1)!}x^{n-k-1}a^k$, which I do not know how to show it is always positive (or negative). Is there a theorem that relates the coefficients of a polynomial to it being always positive or negative?

You should use the LHS instead of the RHS of the equation for the derivative (see my answer).

@JeanMarie, oh wow I see, I was complicating my life a lot with the binomial theorem form of the polynomial ;). Thanks a lot!

Take the derivative under the form
$$P'(x)=n((x+a)^{n-1}-x^{n-1}).$$
Let us consider the case  $a>0$.
Let us show that; for any $x$, $P'(x) > 0$
(as a consequence $P$ will be an increasing function).
Indeed, from the obvious fact that
$$x+a > x$$
we can deduce (because $n-1$ is an odd number) that
$$(x+a)^{n-1}>x^{n-1}$$
(for example, two numbers are ranked in the same order than their third powers).
Remark : It wouldn't be true for an even exponent : for example the  two numbers $-3$ and $2$ are ranked in this way : $-3<2$ whereas their squares are ranked in the reverse order $9>4$.
Similar reasoning in the other case : $a<0$ but with a negative derivative giving a decreasing function.

The problem can be solved in elementary way,  with no application of the differential calculus.
For $a\neq 0$ let's substitute $x=at.$ Then it suffices to verify that the function $f(t)=(t+1)^{2n}-t^{2n}$ is bijective. The function $f$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$ as $$ f(t)= \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}{2n\choose k}t^k$$ It is strictly increasing on $[-1,0],$ as $(t+1)^{2n}$ is strictly increasing there and $t^{2n}$ is strictly decreasing. Thus it suffices to show that the function $f(t)$ is strictly increasing on $(-\infty,-1].$ Let's substitute $t=-1-s.$ Then $s\ge 0. $ It suffices to show that the function $s^{2n} -(s+1)^{2n}$ is strictly decreasing for $s\ge 0,$ i.e. $(s+1)^{2n}-s^{2n}$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty).$ The latter follows from the first part.
